# While loop as a calculated Field in Select Statement

Tags: sql, for-loop, while-loop, newtons-method

I'm trying to implement a calculated field that utilizes Newtons Method. I have f(x) and f'(x) and the calculation works fine when I run it alone for one calculation as a 'while begin' with static parameters. However, I need the Newton's method to run in the SELECT statement for each row in a query in it's own column.

'Perfect world' Pseudo code below:

```
 DECLARE @x AS Float
 DECLARE @count AS INT = 1

 SELECT
   Col1
  ,Col2
  ,Col3
  ,  Set @x = col1 
     Then DO (
       FOR @count = 1 to 100 
           SET @x = @x - f(@x)/f'(@x)
           SET @count = @count + 1  
       NEXT @count ) 
      OUTPUT @x   AS 'Newtons Method'
```

ex: f(@x) = and f'(@x) can be defined arbitrary equations. i.e f(@x) = POWER(@x, 1/2) and f'(@x) = POWER(@x/2, -1/2).

Output would be of the form:

```
 col1    col2     col3     Newtons Method
 float    float    float            float
  .           .            .                 .
  .           .            .                 .
  .           .            .                 .
```

for all records in query .

Restriction 1) I do **NOT** have permissions to create stored procs or functions in my DB.

Restriction 2) I must complete this task only using TSQL.

Is this even possible?

Comment: where do you have `f(x) and f'(x)`? also how should the output look like?

Comment: updated with additional info

Comment: There are two common methods to avoid explicit loops in SQL Server: table of numbers and recursive CTE. In your case the next value of `@x` depends on previous result in a non-obvious way, so recursive CTE may be the only method here.

Comment: Awesome. Recursive CTE seems like a plan of attack here.  So how would I deploy a recursive CTE for every record?